# Moving single message in RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq

I have got several messages on error queue which has name `TestQueue_errors`.

One of the messages on error queue is important and should be moved back to service queue `TestQueue` so it can be processed again. The other messages on error queue are broken and should stay on error queue.

I have tried to do that with shovel plugin but it seems it is able only to move all messages from one queue to another. Is there a way I could achieve that, to move single message from one queue to another?

Comment: you can configure the shovel by using different routing keys

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Rabbit Management does not allow to do it. The only thing you can do is to publish this message again.

Maybe there are some tools which give possibility to achieve it but it is not a standard behaviour.

Here are actions which you are able to perform on the queue (from RabbitMQ Management page):

1. Move all messages from one queue to another
2. Get all messages without requeue option (they would not be in the queue anymore) [image]
3. Get first N messages without requeue option and then move the rest of messages to another queue